# How to properly change a loaded KML in react-leaflet-kml

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, kml, react-leaflet

I am using [react-leaflet-kml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-kml) and the functionality I am trying to make is a list of buttons corresponding to a KML file, which will make the map load/render that KML.

Currently, the buttons simply change a useState containing the kml file which is used in `<ReactLeafletKml kml={kml} />`

This works the first time, when there wasn't a loaded KML file before, but not when I want to switch to another.

How would I make this work?